# Why do Dynamic Named Ranges not work with INDIRECT()?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I am unable to use the `INDIRECT()` function in Excel with some kinds of named ranges. Simple named ranges seem to work okay, but when I have something more complex, I get hit with a `#REF` error.

Here's an example:

[image: Example of INDIRECT not working]

Here, the basic named range `SomeData` works just fine with both `SUM` and `INDIRECT`. It is just a basic collection of the three values there

The more complex named range `MoreData` works with a regular `SUM`, but when trying to use it in an `INDIRECT` function, it stops working, with no clear reason why.
You can see what the MoreData function is there, but in essence, it's meant to take the last 6 entries from the table labeled `tbl_MoreData`.
Here is the formula used for `MoreData`:

```
=OFFSET(tbl_MoreData[[#Headers], [MoreData]],COUNT(tbl_MoreData[MoreData]),0,(IF(Main!$N$13<COUNT(tbl_MoreData[MoreData]), Main!$N$13, COUNT(tbl_MoreData[MoreData]))*(-1)),1)
```

I hope my explanation was not too cluttered. Please comment if something is still unclear and I hope to be able to explain myself better.

Comment: Either you are using Moredatain the definition of Moredata (which obviously can’t work), or there are multiple objects with that name around.

Comment: What happens when you change the defined named of **MoreData** to something different? Excel may be getting confused given that it looks like your `tbl_MoreData` table has a column by the same name.

Comment: ... didn't you already ask this?

Comment: By the way, `INDIRECT` and `OFFSET` should be avoided because they are volatile (always updating). `INDEX` can *usually* be replaced and is more stable and non-volatile (only updates when necessary).

Comment: @Aganju No, I have looked around and there's only one object with that such name, and it's not being used inside itself for its definition

Comment: @TotsieMae I changed both the table column and the name of the data, to no avail. I didn't think it was that because I used a different name in other things I was trying
[Here's what the change looks like: Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/mDOYJV6.png)

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 Similar question, on a different topic. I decided to make a new thread because the question I asked there was technically answered and I didn't want to drag it out in comments.

Also, I will have to look into using `INDEX` if it's more stable

Comment: What does this formula (the one with the defined name) return when evaluated? Copy it into a cell on your worksheet and then evaluate it using the **Formulas** tab. It's possible your error lives in the formula, not in the use of the `INDIRECT` function.

Comment: @TotsieMae If you go through the evaluation, you eventually end up at -16.18, which happens to be the minimum value of the data it's trying to fetch.

I still don't understand why `INDIRECT()` doesn't like it though... 

If I do `SUM(Debt.xlsm!DifferentData)` it works, but `SUM(INDIRECT("Debt.xlsm!DifferentData"))` doesn't work. Surely those two formulae should be totally equivalent?

Comment: The `INDIRECT` function *"Returns the reference specified by a text string."* In other words, it needs to receive an argument that is a reference to a cell or range of cells, and it doesn't seem like that's what you're giving it. You can find the Microsoft documentation for this function [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261).

Comment: @GameSlayar For more info on the differences between these functions, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490652/excel-indirectaddress-vs-offset).

Comment: @TotsieMae Ah, I see. I don't know whether `DifferentData` actually references the cells or whether it's just data.

Comment: Compare it to what returns when you evaluate your `SomeData` formula and see if you can't figure it out.